# SQL create view with 1 to many

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a view in SQL Server for linking in access. My current statement is:

```
CREATE VIEW BookInfo 
AS
    SELECT 
        Book.Title, Author.AuthorFirst, Author.AuthorLast, 
        Language.LanguageName
    FROM 
        Book, Author, Translation, Language
    WHERE  
        Author.AuthorID = Book.Author 
        AND Translation.Book = Book.BookID 
        AND Language.LanguageID = Translation.Language;
```

My expected(intended) output:

```
Animal Farm, George, Orwell, English
Animal Farm, George, Orwell, Japanese
```

It all works except one thing- two of the 5 books have multiple languages. So when the view is opened, they are listed twice- but with the same language both times.

```
Animal Farm, George, Orwell, English
Animal Farm, George, Orwell, English
```

I have 4 tables: book, author, translation, language. Book has a FK to author(references authorid), translation has a FK to book(bookID) and language(languageID). Would a join be what I need to get it to list each separate translation of a book?

edit: example data and table scripts

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
AuthorID INT NOT NULL,
AuthorFirst VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
AuthorLast VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Author ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Author PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID);

CREATE TABLE Book (
BookID INT NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Pages INT NOT NULL,
Author INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Book ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Book PRIMARY KEY (BookID);

CREATE TABLE Language (
LanguageID INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Language ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Language PRIMARY KEY (LanguageID);

CREATE TABLE Translation (
TranslationID INT NOT NULL,
Book INT NOT NULL,
Language INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Translation ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Translation PRIMARY KEY 
(TranslationID);

ALTER TABLE Book ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Book_0 FOREIGN KEY (Author) REFERENCES 
Author (AuthorID);

ALTER TABLE Translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Translation_0 FOREIGN KEY (Book) 
REFERENCES Book (BookID);

ALTER TABLE Translation ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Translation_1 FOREIGN KEY 
(Language) REFERENCES Language (LanguageID);

INSERT INTO Author (AuthorID, AuthorFirst, AuthorLast) VALUES (1, 'GEORGE', 
'ORWELL'), (2, 'WILLIAM', 'SHAKESPEARE'), (3, 'FREDERIC', 'BASTIAT');

INSERT INTO Language (LanguageID, Name) VALUES (1, 'ENGLISH'), (2, 
'JAPANESE'), (3, 'SPANISH');

INSERT INTO Book (BookID, Title, Pages, Author) VALUES (1, 'THE LAW', 50, 3), 
(2, '1984', 120, 1), (3, 'ANIMAL FARM', 240, 1), (4, 'HAMLET', 240, 2), (5, 
'THAT WHICH IS SEEN, AND THAT WHICH IS NOT SEEN', 58, 3);

INSERT INTO Translation (TranslationID, Book, Language) VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2,                             
2, 1), (3, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2), (5, 4, 1), (6, 5, 1), (7, 5, 3);
```

Comment: You really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around more than 25 years now!!! https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I learned what little sql i understand from on the job stuff and the internet. So I would need to use a specific join statement? Would it be an inner join?

Comment: Yup, that's an inner join

Comment: Running with your schema, everything seems to work.  Orwell's Animal Farm is translated into English and Japanese.  Maybe a data issue?

Comment: Excellent job posting ddl and sample data!!!! Most people can't figure it out.

Comment: @Greenspark the scripts work, its just the view giving me issues- books with multiple translations (animal farm, for example) are listed multiple times but with only the english translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use explicit join syntax your query would look like this. Notice I also used aliases to make this look a lot cleaner. I suspect this is still going to return some duplicates because I suspect you have some issues with your data.

```
SELECT b.Title
    , a.AuthorFirst
    , a.AuthorLast
    , l.LanguageName
FROM Book b
join Author a on a.AuthorID = b.Author 
join Translation t on t.Book = b.BookID
join Language l on l.LanguageID = t.Language
```

Comment: That worked, but you're right it does still have the duplicates. I wonder why?. I don't know enough about sql to understand why its duplicating. The translation table has a separate record for each book translation, so its a 1-to-many from book to translation

Comment: Being a data issue you are going to have to find it. Add a where clause to get only a single book. Then start comment out all the joins, add them back in one at a time until you get duplicates. It is either bad data or a bad design. Without more detail it is impossible to know.

Comment: The only duplicates are the books with multiple translations, so I'm thinking its the design. I'll just have to tinker with it until i figure it out i guess. Thank you!!

Comment: So a book that is translated in two languages has two rows in the translation table? The join is most likely the problem. Do you not have the language the book was written in somewhere? Or is it a "translation" for the original? If you could share the table design and a few rows of sample that replicates the problem this is probably pretty simple to fix. See this for some ideas of what you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The "translation" and language tables are a bit of a misnomer- "language" is merely a list of potential languages, translation is what language each book is available in. The whole database is simple, so i'll post some of the table scripts and example data.

Comment: But yes, a book with two languages has two records in the "translation" table.

Comment: Thank you for the ddl and sample data. The only issue there are no duplicates returned with the code I posted here. Two books are returned twice, because they have multiple languages. Maybe you want only row for each book? Or can you explain what you want as output?

Comment: I'm dumb. I didn't re-do the odbc in access. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!! edit: it worked in SSMS, but the results in access are still the duplicates. Guess i'm onto figuring out why access is breaking it haha

Comment: Not dumb...easy thing to overlook. If this worked for you consider marking it as the answer so others know you found a resolution.